# How to know who installed a certificate?

Tags: asp.net, iis, x509certificate, winhttpcertcfg

I need to give an account a permission for a certificate within a group application, in order to solve the fllowing problem:

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority XXX.

I'm using the *winhttpcertcfg* tool, but when I execute it, I get a message saying
this can only be done by the user who installed the certificate.

How can I find out who installed the certificated?